# What references are there in Stewie's Music Video in Family Guy?

Tags: reference, family-guy

In Family Guy S07E07, Stewie makes a music video for *Everything I Do, I Do It For You*:

I have a suspicion that all these clips are references to something.

Are they, and if so, to what are they references?

Comment: Not enough for an answer yet, but I think the close up of hands playing the piano is from an Elton John video, and there is a couple playing basses in a field in Eurythmics “Sweet Dreams.”

Comment: The song is from Bryan Adams, "Every thing I do" and I think the clips were from various music videos.

Comment: @DustinDavis which brings us to my question: which music videos?

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer only because it's too long for a comment. The song is Bryan Adams, "Everything I do" and the clips are from various music videos. I found a partial list on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/familyguy/comments/2di6y7/oceans_three_and_a_half/)

- Muse - The scene were stewie is throwing the phone and breaking the tv with the lamp. "Hysteria" by Muse.
- The White Stripes The scene in Stewie's music video where he's made of Legos is a reference to the video "Fell In Love With A Girl" by The White Stripes.
- The Police - The shot of Stewie dancing in slow motion in a room full of candles is a reference to the 80's video for "Wrapped Around Your Finger" by The Police.
- Across The Universe - Part of Stewie's Music Video he is throwing paint at a canvas much like during the "Strawberry fields" part of this film, except he does not use strawberry juice as paint as well.
- The Birth of Venus - During Stewie's music video, a scene of him standing naked in a clam shell is shown. This is an allusion to the Sandro Botticelli painting, The Birth of Venus.
- A-Ha - The pencil drawing part A-ha from 'Take on me'.
- Fleetwood Mac - The scene in the barn, where stewie is walking closer to the camera is from Little White Lies.
- Pink Floyd and/or Muse - Destroyed Hotel room is either from The Wall motion picture or from the Hysteria video.
- Guns N Roses Estranged - The scene where the kids disapear from the swings. Also, the RIP headstone which writes Stewie Griffin instead of Axl Rose is without question Don't Cry.
- Elliott Smith - Part in the subway, in black and white, Stewie has a red balloon like in Elliott's video of Son of Sam. The scene with the "will work for love" sign may be referencing Usher's Will Work for Love song.
- When Stewie walks across a field with a cello player might be reference to Eurymythics video for "Sweet Dreams (Are Made of This)"
- Marillion - Jumping off a bridge and into the river is from Marillion's Brave movie

Comment: *"Posting this as an answer only because it's too long for a comment"* - But...isn't this an answer anyway? ;-)